# Parsing JSON with JQ

Tags: shell-script, json, jq

I'm using Bash to run the following script snippet on a Linux box.

JSON file contents: `[ { "id": 123456, "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Smith", "email": "user@domain.com" } ]`

The JSON file is stored in the `${data[0]}` array which is piped into the Bash script.

Bash script:

`trafficEmployeeId=123456
cat "${data[0]}" | jq --arg employeeId $trafficEmployeeId '.[] | select(.id == $employeeId) | .firstName'`

And the output from the script should be `John`. But I get nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you assigned shell variable `trafficEmployeeId` with a *number* it will be passed into `jq` script as a *string* argument. 
The solution is to parse the argument as a *number* with ***jq***'s **`tonumber`** function. 
The second moment is that `data[0]` contains the array with only one object, so it's enough to access it directly with `.[0]` and apply simple `if` operator condition.

Complete solution:

```
trafficEmployeeId=123456
echo "${data[0]}" | jq --arg employeeId "$trafficEmployeeId" '.[0] 
      | if .id == ($employeeId | tonumber) then .firstName else empty end'
```

The output:

```
"John"
```

Comment: On newer versions of jq, one could also use `--argjson` instead of `tonumber`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll try this solution and get back to you.

Comment: Your answer led me to the correct solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The main issue in the code is that you're calling `cat` with `${data[0]}` as its argument.  This will cause `cat` to try to open a file with that as its filename. This may be what you mean by "The JSON file is stored in the `${data[0]}` array", but if it means that the file is *literally* stored in the array, then you need to use `printf` to pass that data to `jq`.

There's an additional issue with you trying to compare a number (in the JSON document) with a string (the value of `$employeeId` in the `jq` expression).  This is easily remedied by using `--argjson` in place of `--arg`.  Using `--argjson` will make `jq` assume that the value of the variable that you create is appropriately JSON encoded already.

Your modified script becomes

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

id=123456
jq --argjson id "$id" '.[] | select(.id == $id).firstName' file.json
```

or, if you want to use the value in `${data[0]}`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# other code here setting data[0] to some JSON document data.

id=123456

printf '%s\n' "${data[0]}" |
jq --argjson id "$id" '.[] | select(.id == $id).firstName'
```

If the query `id` comes from user input or some other external process, it may be safer to still use `--arg` and to convert the value in the document to a string to compare with in the `select()` expression:

```bsh
jq --arg id "$id" '.[] | select((.id|tostring) == $id).firstName'
```